# wxWidgets: launching a bunch of code generating output without blocking the window

Tags: c++, algorithm, wxwidgets

For my work, I developped an algorithm that computes stuff (which I'm not allowed to talk about just yet). It is a time consumming algorithm. Due to my sincere hatred of command line hard to configure algorithms, I am developping a GUI tool that should help me configure the algorithm and launch it. Here it is for the background.

Where I'm stuggling is here: I have a bunch of parameters to set, which is fine, and then I hit a generate button. What it does (or what I want it to do) is launch a custom popup wxDialog with a wxTextField containing the log info generated by the algorithm. The custom wxDialog only has construtor that sets the widgets in the right position.

Here is how I coded it so far:

```
void TnF_LoadingFrame::OnGenerate(wxCommandEvent &)
{
    std::cout << "Generating!" << std::endl;

    LogDialog dialog (m_pController,this,-1,_("Generation"));
    {

        wxStreamToTextRedirector redirect(dialog.m_textRedirection);

        m_pController->Generate();
    }


    if(dialog.ShowModal() == wxID_OK)
        std::cout << "Saving to do" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Cancelled" << std::endl;
}
```

As expected, the dialog shows itself only when the algorithm has finished computing. What I would like is for the window to show itself and for the algorithm to run in the background and its logs to be shown in realtime in the textfield. I was thinking in the line of threads, but I am not sure I understand how it works. I was also thinking in the line of an update function that would automatically be called every frame or so in order to let the dialog shows itself and then launch the algorithm in the update function and finally allows the user to exit the dialog.

I hope I am clear. Does anyone has any suggestions, pointers, ...? Help would be much appreciated ! Thanks in advance.

----EDIT----

So I have tried to implement the wxThread stuff with the LogDialog, and there is a problem. It seems that I have done something wrong with the events that are sent from the thread to the log dialog.

What I wanted was to create a thread when the LogDialog is created. Also, the ok button of the logdialog is disabled while the . This thread launches the algorithm so it runs in the background. When the algorithm is finished, it sends an event to the LogDialog. This event is captured by the log dialog, and the callback function enables the ok button, and deletes the thread.

However, it seems that the LogDialog never captures the event, and while the algorithm is running, finishes and an event is sent somewhere, the callback function is never called... Maybe it something I've done wrong. I included the code below. Thanks again for your help.

Here is what I've wrote: the OnGenerate function is as follows:

```
void TnF_LoadingFrame::OnGenerate(wxCommandEvent &)
{
    std::cout << "Generating!" << std::endl;

    LogDialog dialog (m_pController,this,-1,_("Generation"));


    if(dialog.ShowModal() == wxID_OK)
        std::cout << "Saving to do" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Cancelled" << std::endl;
}
```

It creates a dialog that launches a thread. The thread files are as follows:

MyThread.h

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

#include "controller.h"
#include <tr1/memory>

using std::tr1::shared_ptr;

class Controller;

class MyThread : public wxThread
{
public:
    MyThread(shared_ptr<Controller> pController, wxEvtHandler* parent)
    : wxThread(wxTHREAD_DETACHED)
    {
        m_pController = pController;
        m_parent = parent;

    }

    ~MyThread(){}

protected:
    virtual ExitCode Entry();
    shared_ptr<Controller> m_pController;
    wxEvtHandler* m_parent;
};
#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

MyThread.cpp

```
#include "MyThread.h"

DEFINE_EVENT_TYPE(GENERATION_FINISHED_EVENT)
wxThread::ExitCode MyThread::Entry()
{

    m_pController->Generate();


    wxCommandEvent evt(GENERATION_FINISHED_EVENT, wxID_ANY);

    m_parent->ProcessThreadEvent( evt );
    //m_parent->ProcessPendingEvents();

    return 0;
}
```

The log dialog files are as follows:
LogDialog.h

```
#ifndef LOGDIALOG_H
#define LOGDIALOG_H

#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
#include "controller.h"
DECLARE_EVENT_TYPE(GENERATION_FINISHED_EVENT, wxID_ANY)
#include "MyThread.h"

class MyThread;

class LogDialog : public wxDialog
{

public:
    LogDialog(shared_ptr<Controller> pController, wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString & title,
              const wxPoint & pos = wxDefaultPosition,
              const wxSize & size = wxDefaultSize,
              long style = wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE );

    ~LogDialog(){}


    wxTextCtrl *m_textRedirection;

private:
    void OnGenerationFinished(wxCommandEvent &evt);

    shared_ptr<Controller> m_pController;
    wxButton *m_buttonOk;
    wxStreamToTextRedirector *m_redirect;
    MyThread *m_thread;

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()

};

#endif
```

LogDialog.cpp

```
#include "LogDialog.h"

// how to define the custom event
DEFINE_EVENT_TYPE(GENERATION_FINISHED_EVENT)



LogDialog::LogDialog(shared_ptr<Controller> pController, wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString & title,
          const wxPoint & pos,
          const wxSize & size,
          long style)
    : wxDialog(parent, id, title, pos, size, style)
{
    m_pController = pController;

    //some stuff

    m_thread = new MyThread(m_pController,this);
    m_thread->Create();    

    m_thread->Run();
}

void LogDialog::OnGenerationFinished(wxCommandEvent &evt)
{
    m_buttonOk->Enable(true);

    m_thread->Delete();
}



BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(LogDialog, wxDialog)
  EVT_COMMAND(wxID_ANY, GENERATION_FINISHED_EVENT, LogDialog::OnGenerationFinished)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to make it work... I looked at the sample thread code provided with the library. First of all, I started using wxMACROs instead of MACROs. Don't if that helped... but hey, who am I to judge. Next instead of having a:

```
DECLARE_EVENT_TYPE(NAME,TYPE)
```

call in LogDialog.h, and MyThread.h, I use an enum in LogDialog.h:

```
enum{
    wxEVT_COMMAND_MYTHREAD_COMPLETED = wxID_HIGHEST+1
};
```

This seems to be equivalent to declaring the event, and reduces the macro calls everywhere, so less messy.

Then I declare the event table at the beginning of LogDialog.cpp:

```
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(LogDialog, wxDialog)
  EVT_THREAD(wxEVT_COMMAND_MYTHREAD_COMPLETED, LogDialog::OnGenerationFinished)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()
```

Again, don't know if that helped. But the using an EVT_THREAD is probablly better. Finally, and I think it is what did the trick, I create and launch the event as follows:

```
wxThreadEvent evt(wxEVT_THREAD,wxEVT_COMMAND_MYTHREAD_COMPLETED);
wxQueueEvent(m_parent,evt.Clone());
```

This does the trick.

Also the other problem was to get the standard output back and show it in a text control but it seems that

```
wxStreamToTextRedirector(m_textRedirection);
```

is not thread safe... This is a story for another time.

Thanks to @Baxit for his insights.

Answer (score 0):

there are basically 2 options:

- Single threaded Application: Do everything in the main (wx) thread, just implement your algorithm in a loop triggered by an eventhandler, since you want the gui to be responsive and even show output you have to pass processing time back to wx, this can be done by calling [yield (or better safeyield)](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_appinifunctions.html#wxsafeyield), you can do this somewhere in the loop implementing your algorithm
- Multithreaded Application: create a separated thread for your algorithm and use events to communicate with the main thread (and the gui) - take a look at the [wx-wiki page](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Inter-Thread_and_Inter-Process_communication)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it. As I still want my command line program to work, I am going to try the thread stuff. I don't want my algorithm library to be dependant on the wx framework. I'll tell you how I solved the problem.

Comment: I have tried the wxThread stuff, but I ran into a problem. I edited my question to explain my problem. I you have any insight, that would, again, be much appreciated :-)

Comment: try using `wxEvtHandler::AddPendingEvent` or `wxEvtHandler::QueueEvent` if you are using wx3.0 to send your event

Comment: I did try both, but none of them actually work... The thread is running and an event is sent somewhere, but the dialog never receives it (or processes it...)